# Enable javascript within multiple if's?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a few if conditions in the following PHP.

I can't enable the Javascript section which needs to hide the class when the cart "quantity" is more than the balance.

```
jimport( 'joomla.user.helper' );
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$groups = $user->get('groups');


if(in_array(15, $groups)) { 
$carts= VirtueMartCart::getCart();

foreach($carts->cartProductsData as $cartItem)
{
 if($cartItem['virtuemart_product_id'] == $product->virtuemart_product_id){

  echo "<br /> ".$cartItem['quantity']."  already added to cart";
}
if($cartItem['quantity'] == $max_balance) <?php { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.addtocart-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    </script>
<?php } ?>
} }
```

I don't know how to close the first php instance. It refuses.

Comment: `if($cartItem['quantity'] == $max_balance) <?php { ?>` You're already inside PHP tags but you've opened them again. You **cannot** open php tags inside php.

Comment: And after the last if-statement, you also have `<?php } ?>`, then some curly braces after (outside of the PHP-block since you just closed it) and then yet another `?>`.

Comment: So I should just remove the second instance and only use the " { ?> "

Comment: Remove `<?php` from `if($cartItem['quantity'] == $max_balance) <?php { ?>` and remove `?>` from   `</script>
        <?php } ?>`

Comment: You should only close PHP right before `<script` and open it again right after the js-block.

Comment: Thanks a lot @WillParky93 that helped a ton :) Now it's at least working and I can work with it! I wasn't sure of the syntax when using two ifs and if you have javascript or some other code included.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MagnusEriksson I got it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `<?php ... ?>` in side `<?php ... ?>`, this is incorrect syntax.

Use the following:

```
<?php

jimport('joomla.user.helper');
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$groups = $user->get('groups');


if (in_array(15, $groups)):
    $carts = VirtueMartCart::getCart();

    foreach ($carts->cartProductsData as $cartItem):

        if ($cartItem['virtuemart_product_id'] == $product->virtuemart_product_id)
        {

            echo "<br /> " . $cartItem['quantity'] . "  already added to cart";
        }
        if ($cartItem['quantity'] == $max_balance):
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('.addtocart-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            </script>
            <?php
        endif;
    endforeach;
endif;
```

This uses [Alternative Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) which is a preferred method when nesting `PHP` code in `HTML` blocks.

Comment: Thanks a lot mega. I realised my syntax was wrong. Thanks for the advice

Comment: @MailBlade you are welcome, if my solution was helpful please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bit of a mess inside your php code.

I find using the `if () : endif;` notation is more readable when dealing with php+html

```
    <?php
    jimport( 'joomla.user.helper' );
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $groups = $user->get('groups');
    ?>


    <?php if(in_array(15, $groups)): ?>

        <?php foreach(VirtueMartCart::getCart()->cartProductsData as $cartItem): ?>

            <?php if($cartItem['virtuemart_product_id'] == $product->virtuemart_product_id): ?>
                <br /><?php echo $cartItem['quantity']; ?> already added to cart";
            <?php endif; ?>


            <?php if($cartItem['quantity'] == $max_balance): ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $('.addtocart-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                </script>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. Will be testing it out.

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai I think your `foreach` loop is closing at location wrong.